# Gitlab layout totally crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

I shutdown the Gitlab server, then run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and `sudo service gitlab start`

And the view of the Gitlab became that way.
[image]
[image]

Now I can see the a bit normal view by run the server manually, but missing all the images on the webpage view

`RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 1234`

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/uploads/user/avatar/2/Screenshot_2014_3_28_%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%885_40.jpg"):
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a clean first:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clean
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Or in one line, as in this [migration steps page](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/490f99d45e0f610e88505ff0fb2dc83a557e22c5/doc/update/6.5-to-6.6.md#4-install-libs-migrations-etc):

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
```

If the issue persists, try to find the missing elements, as in [this comment](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/129#issuecomment-20725070) (for gitLab-CI, but the same idea would apply here)

Finally, check if recent versions of GitLab don't need some changes in the NGiNX settings, as in [issue 6216](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6216#issuecomment-37117819), for the assets folder to be accessible.

Comment: I've tried your solutions many times, and when I ran sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production
`Could not find rake-10.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`

Comment: @poc ok. I have also added a reference to another recent issue involving assets.