# unfriendly gitlab webconsole layout

Tags: gitlab

I setup my own gitlab server according to official document. So far everything is fine except the web console's layout. It looks like this. not sure how to fix this.

[image: gitlab layout]

Comment: The CSS stylesheets aren't being loaded properly. Use your browser's developer tools to find out where it's looking for them and what's wrong with it. If you can't figure it out, post the URL of the page you're looking at and the URL it's looking for the CSS in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I found the answer at [Gitlab layout totally crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776379/gitlab-layout-totally-crashed)

Thank stackoverflow

sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production